# Partial rendering in yii2 activeform

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii2, active-form

I have an active form under `_create.php` based from the model `Host` which has a dropdownlist based from the model `DeviceType`. I also have a gridview below the activeforms which is based on `ServiceStatuses` and it is PARTIALLY rendered from `service.php`. Each device type id has different services. How can I make the content of gridview dynamically change based on whatever the current value of dropdownlist? Should I use jquery or ajax?

The sql statement I am planning to use is `SELECT id, name from ServiceStatuses where id = *current drop down index*`

Here are the tables:

```
//Host Machine
id, name, devicetype_id
1  HostA  1
2  HostB  1
3  HostC  2
4  HostD  2

//DeviceType
id, name
1  DeviceA
2  DeviceB

//ServiceStatuses
id, name, host_id
1  ServiceA 1
2  ServiceB 1
3  ServiceC 2
4  ServiceD 2
5  ServiceE 3
6  ServiceF 3
7  ServiceG 4
8  ServiceH 4
```

*_form.php*   **(UNSURE how to pass the index HERE as a parameter to `service` action)**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'device_type')->dropDownList($deviceTypeModel, [
    'onchange' => 'show($id)']
    );
?> 

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

which calls the function on my controller

```
function actionShow($id)
{
        $searchModel = new Object;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $id);

        return $this->renderPartial('service', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
use yii\grid\GridView;
?>

<div>
    <?= 
        Gridview::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => 
            [
                'name' => [
                    'label' => 'Services',
                    'attribute' => 'name',
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this works for the chosen index